# Why is this an incorrect proof that subspace of normal space is normal?

Tags: general-topology

I know that closed subspace of a normal space is normal and there are counterexamples if our subspace is not closed, but if we mimic the proof that closed subspace of normal space is normal using an arbitrary subspace, where does it go wrong?

so the proof would go:
Let $(X, \tau )$ be normal and let $A \subseteq X$ be a subspace. Let $C_1$, $C_2 ⊆ A$ be disjoint, nonempty
closed subsets in the subspace topology. Then there exist two sets $D_1$ and $D_2$ which are closed
in $X$ such that $C_1 = A \cap D_1$ and $C2 = A \cap D_2$. We use normality of $X$ to find open sets to separate $D_1$ and $D_2$ and take open sets and intersect A.

Comment: It could be that $D_1$ and $D_2$ are not disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

$D_1$ and $D_2$ are not guaranteed to be disjoint.

If $A$ is closed, then $C_1,C_2$ are themselves closed in $X$ (closed in closed is closed), so no "enlargement" is needed.

In fact, the best we can do in general is to prove that a $F_\sigma$ subset of a normal space is normal (i.e. a countable union of closed sets).